# Compare table one value with two different tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

There are three tables, A,B and C having common columns(name and number)

> 1. Table A have 10 records(say x) which can be only from table B(say, y) and table C(say, z) (like, x = y+z).
> 2. In table A, there are some records whose value is 0 (zero)
> 3. I need to compare those zero value based records using column = name, with other two tables.
> 4. And check the column "number" for the same "name" is also zero (0) in table B and table C?

I tried to write the below sample query to test on my small set of 3 tables data- but for some reasons I am not able to get all the 10 records as a result?

```
SELECT a.name,a.number as A_number, b.number as B_number, c.number as C_number
from A a, B b, C c
WHERE a.name = b.name
```

The above query gives me data as follows in the sqlfiddle-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57f86/1

In the above data- theres no record `name="hello"` 
Can anyone please correct me where I am going wrong? and how to get the exact result? I need all the records from Table A. I know if I use left join it will populate all the left table data even if no match.

> Possibilities: Table A having records, some may be present in table B
>   and some in table C, but not on both.

Comment: use a left join... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57f86/2/0  I'm not sure why C isn't joined so I assume a cross join...

Comment: But maybe you're after something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57f86/4/0

Comment: In the phrase *check the column "number"*, does "check" mean "require" or ""display"?

Comment: I need to display the number, even,if it is zero or non-zero with respect to the Table A records where number = 0. You are right I was thinking to use Left join too, but got confused how to implement with the third table. Need to practice more on sql :(

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT a.*, b.number as bnumber, c.number as cnumber
from a left outer join
     b
     on a.name = b.name left outer join
     c
     on a.name = c.name
where a.number = 0;
```

By the way, here is a [Postgres](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/57f86/1) SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

It's been over 20 years since the JOIN keyword was added to SQL. Use it:

```
select
  a.name,
  a.number as A_number,
  b.number as B_number,
  c.number as C_number
from A a
left join B b on a.name = b.name
left join C c on a.name = c.name
where a.number = 0
```

The key here is the use of `left join`, which allows all rows in table A to be returned, even if there are no matching rows in the other tables.

If you want to just display true/false if the number is zero in the other tables, do this:

```
select
  a.name,
  a.number as A_number,
  (b.number = 0 and c.number = 0) as zero_elsewhere
from A a
left join B b on a.name = b.name
left join C c on a.name = c.name
where a.number = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote `WHERE a.name = b.name`, that restricted the records returned from table A to only those that also exist in table B.  This is not equivalent to a left join.  If you used only a `WHERE` statement you would need to do:

```
WHERE ((a.name = b.name) OR (b.name is NULL))
AND
((a.name = c.name) OR (c.name is NULL))
```

In the comments and other answers, they have been using `LEFT JOIN` which is easier to write and read.  I suggest you adopt that style as it is widely accepted.